# Infinite loop inside custom abstracttablemodel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, infinite-loop

I am getting an infinite loop inside my custom table model. The two println statements in this class get repeatedly printed out once my table has been created. Any reason why this is so?

In addition, there are other println statements that should be executing, but do not, even though the functions that they are monitoring do occur.

```
package client.mainwindow;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class IndexerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
private BatchState bs;

    public IndexerTableModel(BatchState bs){
        this.bs = bs;       
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(){
        int count = bs.getDlr().getNumFields() + 1;
        System.out.println("getColumnCount");//HERE
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column){
        String result = null;

        if(column == 0){
            result = "Record Number";
        }else if(column >= 0 && column < getColumnCount()){
            result = bs.getDlr().getTitles().get(column - 1);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return bs.getDlr().getNumRecords();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Object result = null;

        if(isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex)){
            Cell cell = new Cell(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            result = bs.getValue(cell);
        }else if(columnIndex == 0){
            for(int i = 0; i<getRowCount(); i++){
                setValueAt(i, i, 0);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("getValueAt");//HERE 
        return result;
    }

    @Override 
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column){

        if(isCellEditable(row, column)){
            Cell cell = new Cell(row, column);
            bs.setValue(cell, value);
        }

        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
        boolean edible = false;
        if(column == 0 && column < getColumnCount() && row >= 0 && row <                      getRowCount())
            edible = false;
        else if(column > 0 && column < getColumnCount() && row >= 0 && row < getRowCount())
            edible = true;

        return edible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are causing the endless loop in the model. You're calling `setValueAt()` from `getValueAt()`. Your implementation of `setValueAt()` triggers `fireTableCellUpdated`. This triggers `getValueAt()`. And the loop repeats.

You should not really update the table in `getValueAt()` method, and certainly not call `setValueAt()`. See [How To Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for some examples of table model implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Add some static counter in your class, initialize to 0.
Then in one of these methods which you ntoed, increment the 
counter each time the method is called. Once the counter 
reaches value of say 20 or 30, then throw a new 
RuntimeException("TEST") in this method.

Observe the stack trace you got, it should
show you what creates the endless recursion.

The recursion might be an indirect one like e.g.
*method A calling method B calling method C calling method A*
and thus not really obvious

Alternatively, you can use a debugger for the same thing.